# Are the log levels for HockeyApp the same for both Android and iOS?

Tags: logging, xamarin, hockeyapp

I'm trying to create a common settings file in Xamarin that will be used by both Android and iOS apps. In this shared settings file I wanted to have a property called `int HockeyAppLogLevel` that I can use in both projects.

I need to know if the log levels HockeyApp uses for Android match the log levels used for iOS.

eg. I return 0 from `HockeyAppLogLevel` and it maps to **ERROR** in both the iOS project and the Android project.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

Based on the [documentation](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-cross-platform/how-to-integrate-hockeyapp-with-xamarin):

Android Log levels
[image: Android Log levels]

And for iOS they are:

```
Error = 1

Debug = 3

None = 0

Verbose = 4

Warning = 2
```

I just printed the Enum they provide with the SDK (BITLogLevel).